# Target space of Green's operator on $L^p$-differential forms on closed manifolds

Tags: smooth-manifolds, elliptic-pde, sobolev-spaces, potential-theory, differential-forms

Let $M$ be a closed (i.e., compact without boundary) smooth oriented Riemannian manifold endowed with a **regular atlas** in the sense of C. Scott [1], i.e., with a finite atlas $\mathcal{A}$ so that for any $(U,\varphi) \in \mathcal{A}$ there exists $(V,\psi) \in \mathcal{A}$ so that $\overline{U} \subset V$ and $\psi \vert_U = \varphi$, and let $W^{k,p}(M,\Lambda^k T^* M)$ for $k = 0, 1, 2, \dots$ and $p \geq 1$ be the classical Sobolev space of $k$-differential forms on $M$. With "classical", I mean that it is understood to be the space of all $\omega \in L^1(M, \Lambda^k T^*M)$ ($L^1_{\rm loc}$ in principle, but $M$ is compact) such that all their generalized derivates up to order $k$ belong to $L^p$, and of course $W^{0,p} \equiv L^p$. Scott proves that $M$ can always be endowed with such an atlas and that $W^{1,p}(M,\Lambda^k T^*M)$ is equivalent to the space of $k$-forms $\omega$ belonging to $L^p$ which are provided with generalized partial derivates, and such that both $d \omega$ and $d^* \omega$ belong to $L^p$. This is done by proving an $L^p$-version of Gaffney's inequality. For ease, I will sometimes omit the indication of the domain and the codomain in the sequel and write, for instance, simply $L^p$ for $L^p(M,\Lambda^k T^*M)$.

Let us denote  $\mathcal{H}^k$ the space of harmonic $k$-forms,  $$(\mathcal{H}^k)^\perp := \left\{ \omega \in L^1 : \forall h \in \mathcal{H}^k, \, (\omega,h) \equiv \int_M \omega \wedge \star h = 0\right\}$$
its "orthogonal complement" in $L^1$, and $H : L^p \to \mathcal{H}^k$ the harmonic projection, as defined in [1, Definition 5.8].

Next, for $2 \leq p < \infty$ Scott defines **Green's operator** $G : L^p(M, \Lambda T^*M) \to W^{1,p}(M,\Lambda^k T^*M) \cap (\mathcal{H}^k)^\perp$ as the unique solution to the equation $\Delta G(\omega) = \omega - H(\omega)$,  and he proves (Proposition 5.15) that $G(\omega)$, $dG(\omega)$, $d^*G(\omega)$, $d d^* G(\omega)$, and $d^* dG(\omega)$ are all bounded in (the appropriate) $L^p$, and their norms are bounded by $\|\omega\|_{L^p}$. The same is then true for $\Delta G(\omega)$, giving in any case a meaning to the definition of $G$ as an equality of elements of $L^p$. Of course, this definition extends the classical one in Warner [2, Chapter 6], where the domain of $G$ is $C^\infty$ and the target space is $C^\infty \cap (\mathcal{H}^k)^\perp$. By a duality argument, he is able to extend this definition and these bounds to every $p \in (1,2)$. Specifically, in Definition 5.23, he defines $G : L^p \to W^{2,p} \cap (\mathcal{H}^k)^\perp$ as the unique bounded linear extension of $G : C^\infty \to W^{2,p} \cap (\mathcal{H}^k)^\perp$. The extension is guaranteed to exist by the density of $C^\infty$ in $L^p$ and the previously mentioned bounds (he says).

Now, my question is: shouldn't $G$ be a linear and continuous operator into $W^{2,p} \cap (\mathcal{H})^\perp$ also for $p \geq 2$? (or, viceversa, shouldn't the target space be $W^{1,p} \cap (\mathcal{H})^\perp$ also for $p \in (1,2)$? Since the avalaible bounds on $G$ are the same, what's the difference?) This is not explicitly said in Scott, but presumably true by elliptic regularity (see, for instance, Theorem 4 in Section 5.2.5 of [3]).

A strictly tight question is: is it true that, on a closed manifold, a form $\omega$ with $\omega \in W^{1,p}(M, \Lambda^k T^*M)$, $d \omega \in W^{1,p}(M, \Lambda^{k+1} T^*M)$, $d^*\omega \in W^{1,p}(M, \Lambda^{k-1} T^*M)$ belongs to $W^{2,p}(M, \Lambda^k T^*M)$? Notice that, according to Iwaniec, Scott and Stroffolini [4], this is not generally true if $\partial M\neq \varnothing$ (and it seems to me they do not comment whether this holds or not on a closed manifold), being the space $\mathcal{L}^{2,p}(M, \Lambda^k T^*M)$ of forms $\omega$ with the aforementioned property a proper closed subspace of $W^{2,p}$. So, I am actually asking whether or not $$\mathcal{L}^{2,p}(M, \Lambda^k T^*M) = W^{2,p}(M, \Lambda^k T^* M)$$ for a closed Riemannian manifold $M$, endowed with a regular atlas (which is true when 2 is replaced by 1, see (6.2) of [4]). Of course, if this is true, then also the answer to the first question is in the affirmative.

---

[1] C. Scott, *L^p theory of differential forms on manifolds* Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 347(6) (1995), 2075-2096.

[2] F. Warner, *Foundations of differentiable manifolds and Lie groups*, Volume 94 of Graduate Texts in Mathematics, Springer New York 2012.

[3] M. Giaquinta, G. Modica, J. Souceck, *Cartesian currents in the Calculus of Variations I*, Volume 37 of Ergebnisse der Mathematik und ihrer Grenzgebiete, Springer-Verlag Heidelberg 1998.

[4] T. Iwaniec, C. Scott, B. Stroffolini, *Nonlinear Hodge theory on manifolds with boundary* Ann. Mat. Pura App. (IV), Vol. CLXXVII (1999), 37-115.

Comment: By *closed* manifold  do you mean compact without boundary?  In the noncompact case you need to be careful about the choice of metric. In the compact case the above results are  consequences  of the fact that the operator $d+d^*$  is Fredholm $W^{k+2,p}\to W^{k,p}$, $\forall k\geq 0$, $p\in (1,\infty)$..

Comment: Yes, by "closed" I mean exactly compact without boundary.